# Express.js res.send - Is it in Node.js Manual?

Tags: node.js, http, express

http://expressjs.com/

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);`
```

I can't find the corresponding reference about `res.send` inside Node.js manual:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse

Is it an undocumented property, or id the property an inherent part of HTTP? If so, where can I find corresponding reference on all the properties?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#response.write

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a part of [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.send%28%29), not Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that node.js does not provide advanced functions such as express.js (and it will never, node.js will remain small)

You may want to take a look at [node toolbox](http://toolbox.no.de/) in order to find awesome node libraries